# Cant access TableViewCell elements using UI Automation

Tags: iphone, uitableview, automation, ios4

I have a custom Table View Cell that displays the details of a Conference Call.  The body of the cell's constructor is below:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString*) reuseIdentifier {
 if(self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
      self.contentView.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
      self.contentView.accessibilityLabel = @"Blah";

      conferenceNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
      conferenceNameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
      conferenceNameLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
      conferenceNameLabel.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
      conferenceNameLabel.accessibilityLabel = @"Name";
      [self.contentView addSubview:conferenceNameLabel];

      conferenceDateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
      conferenceDateLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
      conferenceDateLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
      conferenceDateLabel.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
      conferenceDateLabel.accessibilityLabel = @"Date";
      [self.contentView addSubview:conferenceDateLabel];

      recurringIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
      [recurringIconView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
      recurringIconView.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
      recurringIconView.accessibilityLabel = @"Icon";
      [self.contentView addSubview:recurringIconView];

      [self setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
 }

 return self;
```

}

When using UI Automation, I can access the Content View using the accessibility label "Blah".  But I cant access any of my Labels or my ImageView.  Any reason why I can't get at those UI elements using UI automation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within your script, you should be able to log out the accessibility hierarchy for each cell using logElementTree():

```
cell.logElementTree();
```

These subview should appear in that logged tree, along with their accessibility labels.

If you somehow can't address these elements by their label, you should be able to grab them by their relative position in the list of sibling views:

```
var firstLabel = cell.elements()[0];
```

I walk through UI Automation and show examples of how to test out table views like this in my [course on iTunes U](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/advanced-iphone-development-fall-2010/id407243028).

Comment: I'll have to check out your course materials, maybe there will be an "AHA moment" and I'll realize I was doing something silly.

Comment: I had tried logging the element tree but UI Automation reports that my cell has a element list of length 1 and that single element is a UIAElement whose name is the name and date of the conference call and has a value of null.

Comment: @Jonathan - This might be due to the fact that it looks like table cells are accessibility containers: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW3 .  You may need to override the UIAccessibilityContainer protocol methods in your custom table cell to return the proper number of labels and an array of those labels.  However, be aware that this might reduce the accessibility of your application to visually impaired users.